# Alamofire - Authorization Bearer and Authorization Custom

Tags: http-headers, authorization, alamofire, bearer-token

I'll keep the question very short and simple. In the screenshot below the Postman takes two Authorization tokens in the header fields.

[image]

Missing either of the two tokens results in authorization error. I'm unable to send both the headers simultaneously in a request using **Alamofire**. When I send the headers like this:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer " + WSO2AuthToken,
                            "Authorization": "Custom " + customAuthToken]
let request = Alamofire.request(url!,
                                method: HTTPMethod.get,
                                parameters: parameters,
                                encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                                headers: headers)
```

It throughs an error saying:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys

Now the question is how can I send both the tokens in the header of a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get away with it by using `Authorization` and `authorization` as separate keys, which should be interpreted by the server correctly (since headers aren't supposed to be case sensitive). Technically, HTTP headers aren't supposed to have duplicates, aside from a special case for the `Cookies` header, so I'd suggest your custom authorization use a custom header as well, something like `X-Authorization`.